# How to develop user interface for NUnit which will contain all the test and Run button?

Tags: nunit-3.0

Actually, I am working on NUnit and trying to develop user-interface which will contain all the test available in project and Run button in front of them. When this button will be clicked then only test will execute. Please, give me idea how to work on it.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a decent api, you can always run command line with the /run:testclass parameter